# Javascript: detect loading order of JS libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I have a page with Jquery and Prototype loaded. (I don't know the order and have no control of this page)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Later in the same page, I am allowed to embed my own code. I need to know the order of loading these 2 libraries. For example, if prototype lib is loaded first, then do this otherwise do that.

How do I do this with jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: why does it matter which one is first? You can wait for document ready, or simply get all script elements in an array, and loop through to figure out which one comes first with javascript.  If it matters which one loads first, then you don't want to use jQuery, but rather pure javascript.

Comment: Maybe if you can explain why the order matters, you will get a better answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help;

```
    if (jQuery === $) {
        alert("jQuery later");
    }
    else {
        alert("Prototype later");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prevent conflicts between jQuery and prototype it wont matter what order they were loaded in:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); //will return $ to what it had been before jQuery was added
(function ($) {
  //jQuery aliased to $ for use within anonymous closure
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
  //jQuery aliased to $ for use within $(document).ready shortcut
});
```

Comment: I don't know how about your case but the prototype code on my page is not working when prototype lib is loaded After jquery lib AND jQuery.noConflict() is called after that.

I was playing with this myself too and found out about the load order issue. You can see more here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries , and scroll down to "INCLUDING JQUERY BEFORE OTHER LIBRARIES"